# CUDA fails to recognize nvcuda namespace during compilation

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, cuda

I am following the CUDA [tutorial](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/programming-tensor-cores-cuda-9/#disqus_thread) on using the V100 tensor cores.  My MWE code :

```
$ cat src/wmma.cu
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <mma.h>
using namespace nvcuda;
int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with CUDA 9.0,

```
$ nvcc src/wmma.cu
src/wmma.cu(10): error: name must be a namespace name

1 error detected in the compilation of "/gpfs0/scratch/1430008/tmpxft_0002054c_00000000-8_wmma.cpp1.ii".
```

If I add the option `--gpu-architecture=compute_62`, I still get the same error.  `CPATH` is set to `/opt/cuda/9.0/include:`, so I believe that I'm not having difficulty finding the header files.

When I comment out the `using namespace nvcuda`, it compiles and executes as expected.

QUESTION:

1. Why is my compilation of this trivial code failing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is my compilation of this trivial code failing?

Because you must specify a compilation architecture which supports these features, otherwise they are undefined:

```
$ cat nvnvnv.cu 
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <mma.h>
using namespace nvcuda;
int main(void){
    return 0;
} 


$ nvcc nvnvnv.cu 
nvnvnv.cu(3): error: name must be a namespace name

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00005444_00000000-8_nvnvnv.cpp1.ii".
```

The default compilation architecture is `sm_30` on the compiler I am using (CUDA 9.2). Specifying the correct architecture makes the error disappear:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_70 nvnvnv.cu 

$
```

Referring you to the (very useful) CUDA [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info):

> If you are finding that you are getting syntax errors on CUDA keywords
>   when compiling device code, make sure you are compiling using nvcc and
>   that your source file has the expected .cu extension. If you find that
>   CUDA device functions or feature namespaces you expect to work are not found (atomic
>   functions, warp voting functions, half-precision arithmetic,  cooperative groups, etc.),
>   ensure that you are explicitly passing compilation arguments which
>   enable architecture settings which support those features.

Comment: Thanks.  This information about features available for different architectures should really be in `man nvcc` or `nvcc --help`.  Instead I found it here : https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma -- first line of the programming guide describing warp matrix functions

Comment: Ahh, I looked at that previously.  I didn't realize that "...for devices of compute capability 7.0 or higher" translates into `--gpu-architecture=compute_70`